# JavaFX: Access in FXML to a non-String-Object from a ResourceBundle

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, resourcebundle

Lets say I have a Resource class like this:

```
public class Resources extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {

    private static final Object[][] OBJECTS = new Object[][]{
        {"FOO", "foo"},
        {"BAR", 123d}
    }

    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return OBJECTS;
    }
}
```

In my Application class I load the `fxml` like this:

```
Resources resources = new Resources();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/foo.fxml"), resources);
Parent root = loader.load();
```

In my `foo.fxml` I want to use both my String and my double Resource value, like this:

```
<Label text="%FOO">
<Polygon>
    <points>
        <Double fx:value="0"/>
        <Double fx:value="0"/>
        <Double fx:value="%BAR"/>
        <Double fx:value="0"/>
    </points>
</Polygon>
```

The first line works perfectly, but the line with `fx:value="%BAR"` creates Exception as follows:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/foo.fxml:90
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$2700(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$IncludeElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1143)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at my Application class in line Parent root = loader.load();
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "%BAR"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:502)
at com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.coerce(BeanAdapter.java:450)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:982)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
... 17 more
```

So my question is: how to use Resource objects other than `String` in FXML?

**Edit:** Still got this issue. I even tried `{"BAR", new Double(123)}` in my Resource class. The same error appears, which honestly makes sense because this is nothing that logically fixes the exception. I thought about this a lot and I am pretty lost here since I really want this to work and got no idea what to do. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I posted this question on Oracle Community Forums and got an answer: https://community.oracle.com/message/14270285#14270285

The author refers to [FXMLLoader source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.java) where you can see that only `getString` is being invoked by the `FXMLLoader`. Therefore it is simply not possible to do this the way I wanted to. The author continues describing that I could override `FXMLLoader` but the important part, the `resolvePrefixedValue` method, is private saying its a 'no-go'.

In the end I will leave `FXMLLoader` as it is and work with an `Initializable` implementing `Controller` which invokes the `getObject` method from my `Resources` class and adds the values to `Polygon` in `initialize` method. This works fine for me since the important part on my mind is having the values defined inside my `Resources` class.